# Is there some way to figure out why different writing in Swift cause so huge gap of compile time?

Tags: swift, xcode, compilation

There are two different writing:

```
func dicFuncA() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return [
        "a": "ooo",
        "b": 30,
        "c": [1, 2, 3],
        "d": 2.33
    ]
}
```

And

```
func dicFuncB() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
    let dic: [String : Any] = [
        "a": "ooo",
        "b": 30,
        "c": [1, 2, 3],
        "d": 2.33
    ]

    return dic
}
```

When add "-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" to *Other Swift Flags*:

[image]

We can get the compile time of the function:

[image]

The compile time of `dicFuncA` is about 54 times longer than the time of `dicFuncB`!

That's Why?

Probably, it's the cause of type check. But, is there some way to figure out what the compiler have done during the compile time？

I try to use `swiftc` command, like `-dump-ast`/`-dump-parse`, to find out the real reason. But, still confused.

Comment: Probably because of the type inference required.

Comment: did you tried to execute B before A ? Ans run 1 000 times to get an average ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good observation you have made. In Swift when the datatype is not defined the compiler must infer it.
Let's see what [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) says about it:

> ...the type information is passed up from the leaves of the expression tree to its root. That is, the type of x in var x: Int = 0 is inferred by first checking the type of 0 and then passing this type information up to the root (the variable x).

So the compiler must check the type of each tuple in the dictionary and accordingly set the type of the dictionary. This operation is expensive.

Just for fun you can see how compile time correlates to the number of tuples.

Comment: What I want to do is to prove the point by figuring out the progress of compile. Is that means I have to check the source code of swift?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Do you want to reduce compile time?